# Java/Android API understanding

Tags: java, android

I started working on Android applications and I find little difficult to understand this piece of code:

```
LineNumberReader(new FileReader("/proc/tty/drivers"));
```

How can I know that the *LineNumberReader* function accepts *FileReader* as a new instance of the class?  I went through the Java documentation for the *LineNumberReader* API, it doesn't mention anything regarding *FileReader* class.  There is problem in Java API interpretation which I have to consider, Can any one of you please help me in understanding how an API should be used in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you actually saw:

```
new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("..."))
```

The [`LineNumberReader` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) shows a [constructor taking a `Reader` parameter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/LineNumberReader.html#LineNumberReader%28java.io.Reader%29), and `FileReader` extends `Reader`. So think of it like this:

```
Reader reader = new FileReader("/proc/tty/drivers");
LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(reader);
```

Is that clearer for you?

Comment: Thanks Jon, I am clear now . I had one more doubt, in Java documentation [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Reader.html) for Reader class it mentions **Known Direct Subclasses ** and **Known Indirect Subclasses **, I am not sure what is the difference between both ? Can we use both classes as you refereed earlier to Reader or it is just known Indirect Subclasses comes under this category?

Comment: @RajeshSO: The difference is that *direct* subclasses will be ones which extend Reader directly whereas indirect subclasses will be ones which extend some other subclass of Reader. Both can be used as Readers. I would strongly recommend that you read an introductory Java book at this point, to clarify inheritance further.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I am in process of learning Java. Can you suggest any good book to start with Java? I found **Thinking Java** makes sense for beginners, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @RajeshSO: I'm afraid I haven't looked at the set of available beginner books in Java for years - I don't really have any useful advice.

Comment: No issues, Thanks for everything :-)